# Exponential Equation $p \cdot a^x - q \cdot b^x \le c$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I have a hard exponential equation to solve:
Given $p,q,a,b,c$, I need to solve $x$ in the following equation:

$p \cdot a^x - q \cdot b^x \le  c$.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: This is homework? If so, it might be good to give more context, because as stated it's a pretty ugly problem and involves lots of separate case analyses (e.g., if $p < 0$ and $q, c > 0$ then true for all $x$). The solution will always be expressible as a finite union of points and intervals, with the critical consideration being where equality holds. It's possible that solving the equality explicitly can be done via some clever application of the Lambert W function, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $a^x = e^{x \cdot \ln{a}}$. Can you start with this ?